# How to create Nest for elastic conditional source descriptor

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

In my index I have documents of type attraction they have a property which is a list of offers. Those offers have an expiry date. Each attraction can have more then one offer it is possible for an attraction to have one expired and one not expired offer.  What I want to do is when I query and get my results back to not show in the attraction any expired offers.  My source descriptor looks like:

```
.Source(src => src.IncludeAll().Excludes(f => f.Fields(d => d.Offers.Where(df => df.Expires > DateTime.Now)))
```

In the generated query part I can see the following:

```
{ "includes": [ "*" ], "excludes": [ "offers.now.expires"] }
```

I still see expired offers on a given attraction that has expired and not expired offers.  Is it even possible to conditionally filter fields in source descriptor?

I also tried:

```
.Source(src => src.IncludeAll().Excludes(f => f.Fields(d => d.Offers.First().Expires > DateTime.Now))
```

output is same and result is same, i still get expired offers in the returned attraction document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch cant have conditional filter on source. So i thinck Nest allow it in code because of linq but this doesnot work. You have to filter out on client side.

Comment: The lambda expression in `.Field()` are only ever to resolve to a string field name, using the type system.